# Error while setting up wiremock extension

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, wiremock

I am trying to setup my wiremock server with extensions as described in the [official image](https://hub.docker.com/r/wiremock/wiremock). But when I deploy the application via helm, I keep getting error :

```
--extensions com.opentable.extension.BodyTransformer is not a recognized option
```

My setup:

Deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment

spec:
  revisionHistoryLimit: 0
  progressDeadlineSeconds: {{ default 300 .Values.deployment.progress_deadline_seconds }}
  minReadySeconds: {{ default 10 .Values.deployment.min_ready_seconds }}
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: {{ default 0 .Values.deployment.max_unavailable }}
      maxSurge: {{ default "50%" .Values.deployment.max_surge }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.app | quote }}
      country: {{ .Values.country | quote }}
  template:
    metadata:
    {{- include "labels" . | indent 6 }}
    spec:
      {{- include "node_affinity" . | indent 6 }}
      {{- include "node_tolerations" . | indent 6 }}
      initContainers:
        - name: download-extensions
          image: alpine:latest
          command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "wget -O /var/wiremock/extensions/wiremock-body-transformer-1.1.3.jar https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/opentable/wiremock-body-transformer/1.1.3/wiremock-body-transformer-1.1.3.jar"]
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: "/var/wiremock/extensions"
              name: extensions-volume
      containers:
      - env:
        {{ include "dynamic" . | indent 10 }}
        image: "wiremock/wiremock:2.35.0"
        args:
          - "--jetty-acceptor-threads=50"
          - "--jetty-accept-queue-size=50"
          - "--container-threads=100"
          -  "--extensions com.opentable.extension.BodyTransformer"
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: {{ .Values.app }}-{{ .Values.country}}-{{ .Values.environment }}
        ports:
        - containerPort: {{ .Values.deployment.container_port }}
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: {{ default "128m" .Values.deployment.resources.requests.cpu }}
            memory: {{ default "128M" .Values.deployment.resources.requests.memory }}
          limits:
            cpu: {{ default "256m" .Values.deployment.resources.limits.cpu }}
            memory: {{ default "256M" .Values.deployment.resources.limits.memory }}
        readinessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: {{ default 3000 .Values.deployment.container_port }}
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          periodSeconds: 60
          successThreshold: 1
          failureThreshold: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 10
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: {{ default 3000 .Values.deployment.container_port }}
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          periodSeconds: 60
          successThreshold: 1
          failureThreshold: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 10
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /home/wiremock/mappings
          name: {{ .Values.app }}-{{ .Values.country }}-mappings
        - name: "extensions-volume"
          mountPath: /var/wiremock/extensions
      volumes:
      - name: {{ .Values.app }}-{{ .Values.country }}-mappings
        configMap:
          name: {{ .Values.app }}-{{ .Values.country }}-mappings
      - name: extensions-volume
        emptyDir: {}
```

Additional information: In my use case, I want to access request body to send customised response based on certain params hence need the wiremock-extensions to work

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the CLI argument with a space gets escaped incorrectly when being passed to the executable. Try "--extensions=com.opentable.extension.BodyTransformer"